# poetry --help (or any other command) results in Library not loaded: '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/.../3.10/Python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-poetry

I had a poetry project working fine. I re-opened it today for the first time in a while, made some changes (mostly in the app code itself) and ran `poetry install` to update the dependencies.

Any `poetry` command results in

```
Library not loaded: '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Python'

Referenced from: '/Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
```

Any tips on how to get poetry working again?